# For a trade bid must be at least the ask, but what price is actually chosen when they are not equal?

Tags: price, bid-ask

Example:

- I put in a buy order for one share at $100
- Someone puts in a sell order for one share at $90.

Clearly this will result in a trade. But at what price?

Comment: According to https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/110909/what-price-will-a-stock-sell-at-when-theres-a-negative-spread-between-buy-and the short answer it'll use the ask price, in the simplified example. Thanks @glibdud!

Comment: In reality, an HFT will probably detect the sell order, fill the buy for $90 and sell at $100.

Comment: Yeah. But if I now understand right it means that if I put in a buy order for $1000 I'll actually only pay the price of any active sell orders currently on the market, right? (I'm here assuming that there are enough active "asks" to cover my volume, with a price <$1000)